# Linq output multiply results

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a simple SQL query like this :

```
SELECT table1.[idGK]  , table2.FullName , table2.LgotName
 from table2
 join table1 on table2.C_LGT = table1.[idGK] 
where table1.mcod = 41003
```

And i have right output of this :

```
idGK | FullName| LgotName 
------------------------                           
1    |One      |Ball                             
2    |Two      |Wog                           
3    |Three    |Aks  
5    |Four     |Mqi                             
7    |Five     |Thel                           
9    |Six      |Imx
```

But when i make LINQ query of this :

```
IEnumerable<FinalDoc> fidn = from post in repository.table1
join thir in repository.table2 on post.idGK equals thir.C_LGT
where  post.mcod.Trim().Contains("41003")

orderby post.idGK

select new FinalDoc
  {
     mcod = post.mcod,
    FullName= thir.FullName,
     idGK = post.idGK
 };
```

i have this result:

```
    FullName  | LgotName 
    ------------------------                           
    Five      |Thel                             
    Five      |Thel                            
    Five      |Thel  
    Five      |Thel                              
    Five      |Thel                            
    Five      |Thel
```

I try to change table1 and table 2 to make right join but i have same result.
What linq query i need to do to make same result that in SQl ?
P.S EF , Linq , Asp.net , Web Forms

Comment: why is this difference `where table1.mcod = 41003 ` in SQL and `post.mcod.Trim().Contains("41003")` in Linq ?

Comment: perhaps because  the sql query uses equal and the linq query uses contains( sql like "%something%")? this means the sql query will match 41003 with 41003  and the linq query can match 41003  with 141003,410032,87234741003342,etc

Comment: Did you try to check the running SQL query that is generated from Entity Framework?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy If i use post.mcod ==  "41003" in linq i have empty result

Comment: @jannagy02 i only check it in ms sql , how can i check what is generated from EF?

Comment: @Андрей Голубцов you can use the LinqPad https://www.linqpad.net/ to check your results.

Comment: The best way in my opinion is runing this before the query: #if DEBUG repository.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); #endif And check the output of Visual Studio while running in debug mode.

Comment: @Lidaranis If i use post.mcod == "41003" , not contains , i have nothing in output .

Comment: Can you remove the `where` condition and check if the data contains all the records? Just to make sure the issue is with the `where`  only

Comment: @RajshekarReddy if i remove where clause i have all records

Comment: @AfnanAhmad i install linqpad , how can i convert it to linq?

Comment: Can you add your Model definitions for those two tables..

Comment: @Андрей Голубцов you can open two query windows and select your language from dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this, but answer is very simple :
My problem was that i didn't add to my class definition  primary key row , because of that i have this result .
In my table i didn't have primary key , and i add id row, because EF needs primary key , and if you didn't add them , EF will do this work for you(and take first line ) . In my case i add idG row:

```
[Key]
    public int idG {get;set;}
    public int idGK { get; set; }
    public string mcod { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ equivalent of your SQL query is:

```
from thir in repository.table2
join post in repository.table1 on thir.C_LGT equals post.[idGK]
where post.mcod == 41003
```

So assuming your SQL is correct (i.e. table1.mcod is a numeric type and not a string) then it should work.

**EDIT:**
You could try this to see what SQL EF is generating from your LINQ. It may help diagnose the problem.

```
var query = from post in repository.table1
join thir in repository.table2 on post.idGK equals thir.C_LGT
where post.mcod.Trim().Contains("41003")

var sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();
```

Comment: i test my query in linqpad and it right , as yours too. I check variables , its all right types, maybe problems with my EF, but i didn't know where to see, because another queries works well.